# How can i give the values from one class to another in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

Actually, i have some values calculated in my viewController.m of my project.And i use that final result in another class(uiview class) to draw that.But i can't understand how can i use the calculated values in my other class of same project in iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with following steps

1. Declare the variables in delegate.h file
2. write @property for the variable
   e.g.`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string;`
3. Synthesize in delegate.m

   @synthesize string;
4. In the class(.h) where you want to use it

   //import yourDelegate.h
   YourDelegate *mainDelegate;
5. In .m file

`mainDelegate =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];`

Answer (score 2):

When pushing a new view you can call methodes of that view. Don't know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

use setters and getters its essay for a beginner,or else go for property and synthesize.use this [reference](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

Before you push into your new view you can pass variables accross.

E.g.

```
ViewController * viewcontroller = [ViewController alloc] init;
//pass your variables in here by setting the variables in the view your pushing into
viewcontroller.calculation = self.calculation;
//push into new view 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES]; 
[viewcontroller release];
```

this allows you to set the variable calculation in your new class by making it equal your calculation variable on your original view, before pushing to the new view.